# TypeScript no error on non-matching return value

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't TypeScript complain about this?

```
async GetCategoriesBySet(set: Set): Promise<Result<Array<ProductCategory>>> {
  let categories: Array<ProductCategory> = []

  if (!set.theme || !set.subtheme || !set.title) {
    return Promise.resolve(new Result<Array<ProductCategory>>({res: null, err: "Set data is not valid"}))
  }

categories.push(await this.GetCategory(set.theme, {parent: (await this.GetCategory('Themes')).id}))

  return categories
}
```

The return value, `categories`, is of type `Array<ProductCategory>`, not a Promise, or even the wrapping `Result` class. So why is it happy to let me make this mistake? (And is there any way to get it to complain?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The return value, categories, is of type Array, not a Promise,

All `async` functions return a `Promise`. This is a part of the JavaScript spec. If you return a constant it is essentially `Promise.resolve`ed.

Answer (score 0):

When your function declares `Promise<Result<Array<ProductCategory>>>` return type you can return value of type `Result<Array<ProductCategory>>`.

If I have following declaration:

```
interface Result<T> {
    result: T;
}
```

I receive error from TypeScript compiler:

`Property 'result' is missing in type 'ProductCategory[]'.`

What is your definition of `Result`?